# MissingPropertyException for Gradle Plugin - Cannot find task type

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am currently in the process of re-organizing and re-structuring some of the projects we use at work.

One of my goals is to integrate a project's unit tests correctly. I have upgraded the root projects Gradle to the latest version (5.6.2) and I have made all the necessary DSL changes.

Right now I'm in the process of including the project's integration tests under its source code. For this I created a new subproject.

So far so good but when I attempt to build the project it fails with following exception:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'StartServerTask' for project ':integration-tests' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:84)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(BasicScript.java:156)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:61)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.getProperty(BasicScript.java:65)
```

Now, the task in question comes for a Gradle plugin a colleague created in the past. Said plugin is fetched from a maven repository as a dependency like so:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'maven_link' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'fts.gradle:start-server:0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'eclipse'
}
```

And applied like

`apply plugin: 'fts.gradle'`

I have tried almost everything, even changing the package structure of the plugin, but I am unable to include it properly in the build file.

If I copy paste the code directly within the project's build.gradle everything works fine but it doesn't so if I try to remote fetch and include the plugin.

Can anyone provide any insight to this?

Comment: You probably need to import the task type class or reference it via its full name (`package.of.StartServerTask`).